# Swift app with SpriteKit: normal to have 30% CPU usage with only 5 nodes and no active processing?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

For an iPhone app using Swift and SpriteKit, is it normal to have 30% CPU usage with only 5 nodes and no active processing (i.e., the app waits for user tap/pan before doing anything and hits 30% upon rendering the initial scene), or does this suggest something wrong with our code?

Instruments.trace linked here: http://www.filedropper.com/instruments2trace

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code with the time profiler in Instruments?

Comment: Yes, but as we're new to Swift and iOS dev, the data is very confusing. :) So 30% CPU usage is high?

Comment: It seems high to me, but I've never done any SpiteKit work. It probably depends on the device you're talking about and things like what kind of physics you're doing. You might try posting the Instruments trace.

Comment: Just uploaded the instruments trace ... thanks for your help. have you done any Swift by chance? Curious if you're open to some consulting.

Comment: @Crashalot Your trace shows that you were running your game in the simulator. Have you tried running on a real device? I've noticed simple SpriteKit games having abnormally high CPU usage in the simulator, when they may only require 0-3% usage on a real device.

Comment: @0x7fffffff on the device CPU usage drops to 10%-15% under the same conditions. is this okay?

Comment: @Crashalot You might want to upload the Instruments trace from your device and (ideally) some minimal sample code that produces the behavior you're seeing. Can you also confirm that you're running your app with optimizations turned on? (e.g. "Release" rather than "Debug")

Answer (score 0):

There is very high CPU usage for SpriteKit in the simulator.